# MapKit: Do locations on a map have unique id's?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I'm trying to make something where you search for something and it shows the locations a map. I am wondering if there is a way to get a unique id for a location (using mapkit and corelocation) so that I can store it for later. After that, when someone searches some locations and the one with the id that is saved is there, I do something else

Basically I need to get a unique id for a certain location to do something to it later. Right now I'm using the latitude and longitude, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "locations?" MKPlacemarks? MKAnnotations? CLPlacemarks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look into `MKAnnotation`. That way you can create an annotation for each location you want to save and then later retrieve them.

From the [MKAnnotation docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/):

> The MKAnnotation protocol is used to provide annotation-related
>   information to a map view. To use this protocol, you adopt it in any
>   custom objects that store or represent annotation data. Each object
>   then serves as the source of information about a single map annotation
>   and provides critical information, such as the annotation’s location
>   on the map. Annotation objects do not provide the visual
>   representation of the annotation but typically coordinate (in
>   conjunction with the map view’s delegate) the creation of an
>   appropriate MKAnnotationView object to handle the display.

Comment: I am using that, but I'm trying to find a unique id to save from each annotation/location so I can save information about that location and show it in the annotation later on.

Comment: Where do you want to store these unique IDs? Is there any reason you can't save the annotation itself?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848404/add-custom-property-to-mkannotation/14849070#14849070

Comment: I'm saving them in parse so I can store other data about them (user entered entries) which can be accessed by others.

Answer (score 0):

A *position* is identified by its latitude and longitude (and altitude if you consider 3 dimensions).

When you say *location*, however I assume you mean more than just position.  For example, a restaurant and a bar may be at the same *position* in terms of latitude and longitude, but are different *locations* when you consider their name, type of business and so on.

If you create a table in Parse to store locations then you can add columns for all of these attributes, and when you save an object to this table, Parse will assign that object a unique identifier.  This object is how you will identify and refer to locations in your app.

You can store a position in Parse using a `PFGeoPoint`, which is simply a convenient way of storing a latitude and longitude (and Parse has support for identifying nearby positions in a query).

Comment: So I should save a location as a PFGeoPoint and then when something is searched, check if that PFGeoPoint exists and if it does, add info to it?

Comment: I think that there may be something missing from your question.  Where are you searching for your locations if not your own Parse database?  This is what you need to look at to determine if it has some existing identifier that you can use.